# Excluir carpeta de la publicación web

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013

Tengo un proyecto web en visual studio, y deseo excluir una carpeta llamada images

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para que cada vez que publico

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ésta carpeta no se publique en el servidor. ¿Cómo puedo hacer eso?

Comment: has intentado con: click derecho sobre la carpeta, excluir del proyecto?

Comment: Es que no quiero excluir la carpeta del proyecto, necesito mantenerla por asuntos del Team Foundation. Lo que necesito es solamente excluirla de la publicación, no del proyecto.

Comment: agrega mayores detalles a tu pregunta, todo ese background que falta mencionar ayudará a que te habiliten la pregunta. Saludos :D

Comment: Es que no sé que más detalles agregar, es simplemente como se muestra en las imágenes adjuntas, la carpeta que se marca en un circulo rojo, necesito que no se publique en el servidor destino, cuando le doy clic derecho --> Publicar.

Comment: necesitas 1 voto más para que habiliten tu pregunta y así respondemos con ganas, un detalle que sirve es decir eso: "Es que no quiero excluir la carpeta del proyecto, necesito mantenerla por asuntos del Team Foundation. Lo que necesito es solamente excluirla de la publicación, no del proyecto", también sería de mucha utilidad si agregas el o los motivos de dicha exclusión.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ve a la carpeta donde está tu proyecto, en la raíz encontrarás el archivo  (.csproj o .vbproj), abre dicho archivo con un editor cualquiera (inclusive el block de notas ayuda!)

Agrega la siguiente línea en el **PropertyGroup** general:

```
<ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>Recursos\images</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
```

Sucede que hay 3 PropertyGroups:

- General: Se encuentra en la parte superior (Aquí es donde tienes que definirlo)
- Debug: `<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">`
- Release: `<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'">`

Guardas el archivo, al ir al Visual Studio te dirá que recargues el proyecto (aceptas) y finalmente haces la publicación sin la carpeta definida.

Comment: Funcionó a la perfección, cabe añadir que en caso de querer excluir más de una carpeta, simplemente se deben separar por punto y coma `<ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>Recursos\images;Recursos\css</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>`. Muchas gracias.

Comment: de nada hermano :D gracias por agregar ese detalle y que le sea de utilidad a más desarrolladores :D